# find() method does not work for elements inside <svg> tag

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am currently trying to scrape a website, and the required data is inside `<svg>` tag.  I try to use `find()` method of bs4 module, but it does not work. What else can I try?

**SVG data sample**

```
<svg height="24" width="48" class="timer">
    <rect x="0.75" y="0.75" height="22.5" width="46.5" 
          class="main_rect"></rect>
    <text x="24.25" y="12.25" class="text">Some text</text>
    <rect x="0.75" y="0.75" height="22.5" width="46.5" class="progress_rect">
</svg>
```

I need to get the `<text>` tag, but `find()` method does not work.

Comment: Can you edit your question and put there sample of the your html/svg data?

Comment: @AndrejKesely just did it, check it out

Comment: can you share the url?

Answer (score 0):

```
    page2 ='<svg height="24" width="48" class="timer"><rect x="0.75" y="0.75" height="22.5" width="46.5" class="main_rect"></rect><text x="24.25" y="12.25" class="text">Some text</text><rect x="0.75" y="0.75" height="22.5" width="46.5" class="progress_rect"></svg>'
    
    
soup = BeautifulSoup(page2, "html.parser")
    
    
    
    
    
print(soup.select('text.text')[0].text)


C:/Users/KT_LAB/Desktop/test/kakao.py
Some text
```

how about use select ?

Comment: The problem is that the text inside <text> tag is dynamic